# angular-formly using angular-translate for global validation message

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate, angular-formly

Validation Message can be configured globally like here http://docs.angular-formly.com/v5.2.1/docs/formlyvalidationmessages

I like to use the translation filter, so that written validation errors are translated in the configured language. Does someone know how this can be done?

Comment: Can you post a little more code showing where you will take these and display them to the user? e.g. is it in JavaScript (service, controller etc), or the template?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using something like this to set your validation message:

```
var field = {
  type: 'whatever',
  templateOptions: {
    pattern: /some_crazyPattern/,
    patternValidationMessage: '"Needs to match " + options.templateOptions.pattern'
  }
};
```

Using angular translate, within the js code $translate can be used for this:

```
$translate('some.message').then(function(response) {
  var field = {
    type: 'whatever',
    templateOptions: {
      pattern: /some_crazyPattern/,
      patternValidationMessage: response.some.message + 'options.templateOptions.pattern'
    }
  };
});
```

Is this helping?

Answer (score 0):

If your defining a field with a validator, you can use:

```
validators: {
  validUntilDateAfterValidFromDate: {
    expression: (viewValue, modelValue) =>  this.validateValidUntilDate(modelValue),
    message: '"some.translate.code" | translate'
  }
}
```

If you want to use the more generic approach by adding formlyValidationMessages to your formly config, you can add a wrapper  to your formlyconfigprovider:

```
formlyConfigProvider.setWrapper({
  name: "field-message",
  templateUrl: "/app/formly/wrappers/field-message.html"
});
```

with field-message.html:

```
<formly-transclude></formly-transclude>
<div class="messages" ng-messages="fc.$error" ng-if="fc.$touched">
  <div class="alert alert-danger"
     ng-message="{{::name}}"
     ng-repeat="(name, message) in ::options.validation.messages"
     translate>
    {{message(fc.$viewValue, fc.$modelValue, this)}}
  </div>
</div>
```