# angular-formly validation messages translation using angular-translate

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate, angular-formly

I am trying to translate `formlyjs` required validation message in `angularjs` that's the code what I have tried but it doesn't translate or bring the translated string in "**REQUIRED**" I am using angular-translate.

**Output** i am getting **`UsernameREQUIRED`** instead of **`Username is required`**
I have looked at this question and answer over [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977451/angular-formly-using-angular-translate-for-global-validation-message). it works with out `to.label` but i need to have this `to.label` concatenation.
Any help or suggestion please.

```
 $translateProvider.translations("en", {
        REQUIRED: "is required",
      })



 formlyValidationMessages.messages.required = 'to.label + "REQUIRED" | translate'; 

 angular.module('templates/formly/validation-messages.html', []).run([
    '$templateCache',
    function ($templateCache) {
      $templateCache.put('templates/formly/validation-messages.html',
        '<formly-transclude></formly-transclude>' +
        '<div class="validation-messages" ng-messages="(fc[0] || fc).$error" ng-if="(options.formControl[0] || options.formControl).$touched || (options.formControl[0] || options.formControl).$error.required || form.$submitted" ng-messages-multiple>' +
        '    <div class="label label-danger animate vanishIn enter-vanishIn exit-vanishOut" ng-message="{{::name}}" ng-repeat="(name, message) in ::options.validation.messages">' +
        '   {{message((fc[0] || fc).$viewValue, (fc[0] || fc).$modelValue, this)}}' +
        '    </div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '');
    }
  ]);
```

Comment: @pascal-precht any help please. Thank you

Comment: try adding a space in `REQUIRED` eg: `'to.label + " REQUIRED" | translate'`

Comment: @Chandan thanks for your comment i have tired that but it didnt work.

Comment: I don't know formly, but Html and angular-ly speaking, this won't work : `{{to.Label "REQUIRED" | translate }}` result:`{{to.Label "REQUIRED" | translate }}`, While this will work : `to.Label {{ "REQUIRED" | translate }}`, result: `to.Label is required`. You may test it here : https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.filter:translate